# Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'unknown.channel.name

Tags: java, spring-cloud-stream, spring-rabbit

I am trying to run the publisher and subscriber, using spring binding.

made sure the destination(exchange) is created locally on the rabbit-mq.

publisher (app.yml)

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        output:
          destination: HelloDestination
  rabbitmq:
    addresses: xxx.xxx.xx.xxx
```

Subscriber(app.yml)

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        input:
          destination: HelloDestination
  rabbitmq:
    addresses: xxx.xxx.xx.xxx
server:
  port: 8081
```

publisher (pom.yml)

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Subscriber (pom.yml)

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

publisher (source java file)

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(Source.class)
public class Demo1Application {

    //@Autowired
    //private static MessageChannel output;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Demo1Application.class, args);

        String sampleMessage = "Hello";
        Message<String> message =
                MessageBuilder.withPayload("Hello World").build();

        MessageChannel output = new DirectChannel();

        output.send(message);   

    }

}
```

//consumer (source file)

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(Sink.class)
public class Demo2Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Demo2Application.class, args);
    }

    @StreamListener(Sink.INPUT)
    public void listenerMethod(Message<String> message)
    {
        System.out.println("The Message is :"+message);
    }
}
```

//----

After doing all, I see the exchange created and also the message on exchange. The consumer starts up just fine. but the producer chokes when trying to send the message with the error message

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'unknown.channel.name'.; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=Hello World, headers={id=ccf86001-5dba-6c64-bc76-e1f58782de42, timestamp=1558883876384}], failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=Hello World, headers={id=ccf86001-5dba-6c64-bc76-e1f58782de42, timestamp=1558883876384}]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:461)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:401)
    at com.example.demo.Demo1Application.main(Demo1Application.java:29)
Caused by: org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=Hello World, headers={id=ccf86001-5dba-6c64-bc76-e1f58782de42, timestamp=1558883876384}]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:138)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:105)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscri
```

I expected the message to be read.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get channel 'output' from the application context returned by the run() method instead of creating your own DirectChannel.

Comment: Thanks Gary, I figured that the issue was creating a local direct channel inside my main. I moved the code over to another class annotated with component, created the channel through autowiring, and had a small method to send the message.. Later used the bean from the application context and published the message. thanks for the prompt reponse.